# Is a free, publicly downloadable edition of Visual Studio 2010 available?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Can I download this IDE for free?

When will the beta expire?

Comment: Have an MSDN membership?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the beta free [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dd582936.aspx). But that will expire before too long, after which you'll have to download the Express editions.

Comment: There are also trial versions, though obviously those cannot be used to develop commercial software.

Answer (score 3):

Well, right now this is in beta... but more then likely, once it comes out, there will be "Express" free versions just as with 2008 and 2005.

That's just my educated guess... I don't know for sure that MS will release Express versions, but probably.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Do you mean legally? That's a different question.

Comment: Do you mean "legally, not in Somalia"? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Right now the beta is free, if you qualify for [BizSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/BizSpark/) you can get the RTM version for free as well.

Answer (score 0):

All of the Express versions of Visual Studio are free but the other versions are not.

Comment: Correction: Express, not Expression

Answer (score 0):

If you're at a school that has MSDN AA, then yes.

How do you normally get new software right now?